# how to make nautilus smarter?

Tags: nautilus

when I copy to external drive I get  : Filesystem does not support symbolic links, how can I modify nautilus to copy the file , not the symbolic link.
Yes I could copy to a local directory or compress. My question is : how could I modify nautilus so I don't have to think about it.

Comment: This is not a matter of making nautilus "smarter". It is a matter of your preference. I may prefer that a symbolic link stays a symbolic link, hence is not copied as such. Still, an option to dereference obviously would be useful for more advanced users. I guess one could brew a Nautilus script or a Python extension that copies recursively a selected item, while dereferencing symbolic links.